# matplotlib bar chart: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, timestamp, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar chart using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(my_df.my_timestamp.astype('str'), my_df.data_count, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

But got the errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-0a7a045df38c> in <module>()

      8 
----> 9 plt.bar(my_df.my_timestamp.astype('str'), my_df.data_count, alpha=0.5)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in bar(left, height, width, bottom, hold, data, **kwargs)
   2648     try:
   2649         ret = ax.bar(left, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, data=data,
-> 2650                      **kwargs)
   2651     finally:
   2652         ax.hold(washold)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1817                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1818                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1819             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1820         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1821         if pre_doc is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)
   2085                 edgecolor=e,
   2086                 linewidth=lw,
-> 2087                 label='_nolegend_'
   2088                 )
   2089             r.update(kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    638         Patch.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    639 
--> 640         self._x = float(xy[0])
    641         self._y = float(xy[1])
    642         self._width = float(width)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2015-12-14'
```

Any idea what I did wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `.astype('str')`? Maybe you mean `.astype(str)`, but even then I don't understand why you would to do that for plotting. Try `my_df.plot(kind='bar')` instead. If that doesn't work, I suggest you providing us with a sample of your data.

Comment: Or if `my_timestamp` is a column in your dataframe, then `my_df.plot(x='my_timestamp', y='data_count', kind='bar')` might be what you need.